flow_view function low resolution
I am trying to visualize a large function via a flow diagram. I am trying to use the function flow_view() from the package: flow. This is working as intended, but I am not able to save the diagram in a high resolution, as it is not seen as a plot. A reproducible case would be::
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE)) 
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("GRmetrics")
flow::flow_view(GRmetrics::GRdrawDRC)
does anyone know of a way to save a diagram like this in a high resolution html / pdf etc. or any ideas on how to visualize these type of functions?
Thanks in advance :)

See this thread on flow's github: very large flow diagrams

You can output to html with flow::flow_view(GRmetrics::GRdrawDRC, out = "test.html)
